# Birth dates like "YYYY-00-00" / "00/00/YYYY"

Tags: database, algorithm, date, formatting

In my country (France), some people have a birth date like `YYYY-00-00` (`00/00/YYYY`). That's a legal convention (and used on identity cards), usually for immigrants who don't know their exact birth date.

Of course that's a problem in databases and algorithms.

Did you ever encountered this situation? How do you deal with it? What would be your choice?

Comment: Is "AAAA" here the "AAAA" string literal, or is it intended to be a placeholder for an actual date, e.g. a birth date can be `1950-00-00`?

Comment: I guess `AAAA` in French is `YYYY` in English: It's a placeholder for a 4-digit year. The question is about the zero day and month.

Comment: Sorry, it should be YYYY. I fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible solutions for your problem, let me describe them:

1. Your solution solves the problem, but creates several new problems. Moo-Juice pointed out one of the problems, but there are several other problems as well. For instance, at application level it will be increasingly difficult to handle those dates, because I believe you will have problems converting those values to dates. Also, it is not nice to have difficulty in reading the month and the day of the date. You will have to deal with thousands of string parsing just to read the days.
2. You can use 3 columns. One for the year, another for the month and another for the day. If the day or month is 0, then we are talking about an immigrant with uncertain birth date.
3. You can also resolve the issue at application level by setting the date with the given year and a default month/day. Of course, you will have to choose the default month and day wisely. The most simple is to choose January 1st as the default date. However, if I were you, I would check the answer to the following question:

> If an immigrant was born in 2000 and his/her birth month and day is
>   not known, then what will be the exact day according to the French
>   legislation the given person will be considered and allowed to vote in
>   2018?

I would choose the third option, because it simplifies the handling method of the value, keeping its atomicity and its type can be date. Also, if you have to change the default value, then it will be simple to do that by changing the algorithm of storing. A possible problem would be that you have to change the default date and apply that to the immigrants already stored in the database. To prevent the serious consistency problem which is threatening your application you can create another column in your table for UnkownBirthDate so in the case of changing the default date you will know whose date should be changed from your already stored users/people.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As I rarely need to make calculations with birth dates (just sometimes to determine the age), I store it as strings, and replaces it with `01/01/YYYY` when I need to use it as a date.
But I don't know how the age is legally calculated, and I'm not happy with it semantically.

Comment: You might also come across sorting problems when storing them as strings.  You may not need to do calculations but sorting might well be an issue.